# PHP Pagination IF Current Page

Tags: php, if-statement, pagination

I have got this pagination I'm got working using PHP, it works great, but while making this work, I've forgot that the user will need to know which page they are currently on.

Would there be an easy way to add to this so if the page number is the same as `$_GET['page']`I can add a new class to the div? I have tried doing another if statement but haven't managed to get anything working, so any guidance would be great!

```
  <?php
    $totalpage      = $values2->SearchPropertiesPagingTotalPropertiesResult / $_GET['perpage'];
    $currentpage    = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1);
    $firstpage      = 1;
    $lastpage       = ceil($totalpage);
    $loopcounter = ( ( ( $currentpage + 2 ) <= $lastpage ) ? ( $currentpage + 2 ) : $lastpage );
    $startCounter =  ( ( ( $currentpage - 2 ) >= 3 ) ? ( $currentpage - 2 ) : 1 );

    if($totalpage > 1)
                    {
                        $pagination .= '<div class="text-center m-t-40"><nav><ul class="pagination pagination-lg">';
                        $pagination .= '<li ><a href="#" aria-label="Previous Page"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></li>';
                        for($i = $startCounter; $i <= $loopcounter; $i++)
                        {

                            $pagination .= '<li><a href="'. $agencyurl .'/search/'. $_REQUEST['bed'] .'/'. $i .'/'. $_REQUEST['perpage'] .'/'. $_REQUEST['area'] .'">'. $i .'</a></li>';
                        }
                        $pagination .= '<li ><a href="#" aria-label="Next Page"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>';
                        $pagination .= '</ul></nav></div>';
                    }
                echo $pagination;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = $startCounter; $i <= $loopcounter; $i++)
{
if ($_GET['page'] == $i) {
     $pagination .= '<li><span class="current">' . $i . '</span></li>';
} else {
    $pagination .= '<li><a href="'. $agencyurl .'/search/'. $_REQUEST['bed'] .'/'. $i .'/'. $_REQUEST['perpage'] .'/'. $_REQUEST['area'] .'">'. $i .'</a></li>';
  }
}
```

Adding an IF condition inside the loop will let you control the pagination design.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `for` loop, break the opening of the `<li>` and then continue:

```
for($i = $startCounter; $i <= $loopcounter; $i++)
{
    $pagination .= '<li '
    if ($i == $currentpage) $pagination .= 'class=".current"';
    $pagination .= '><a href="'. [...]
}
```

Now all you need to do is to style your new `.current` class in your CSS.